# How can I easily break from a wrapping container?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-width container to center some content:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

<div class="container">
    content…
</div>
```

Now I’d like to create a horizontal rule inside the content:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Content foo…</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Content bar…</p>
</div>
```

I like the rule to span the whole page, not just the container. I can do that by pulling the `<hr>` element out of the container:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Content foo…</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <p>Content bar…</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the `<hr>` span the whole page width without taking it out of the container?

Comment: You clearly understand the problem...is there a reason why the obvious solution is not appropriate? However this may offer a solution: http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Comment: The content is rendered in a partial view somewhere inside the website, so I’d rather not care about any containers that might be wrapped around it. And thanks for the link, that’s very close to what I’m after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the natural answer is to change the way you are laying out your containers but to answer your question as you put it you can use `position: absolute` and then the CSS adjacent sibling selector `+` to add some space for the hr after it get's take out of the flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/w248Y/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Content foo…</p>
    <hr/>
    <p>Content bar…</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

hr {
    left: 0;
    margin: 1em 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

hr + * {
    /*Doube the hr margin for even layout */
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is taking the `hr` out of the flow document like this:

```
hr {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XN68a/)**

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**:

```css
.container {
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
}
.container p {
    width:1000px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="container">
     <p>Content foo…</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Content bar…</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.. there is no easy way.  The easiest way to do what you are trying to achieve is to simply wrap each P in its own container and use the HR outside of each container.  http://jsfiddle.net/eEM5G/  Let me know if this helps you out.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Content foo…</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <p>Content foo…</p>
</div>


.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```